# Not able to find classes in org.eclipse.jetty.websocket package

Tags: java, jar, websocket

I'm now trying to use websockets in my application.
I know that I will be required to use the classes WebSocket and WebSocketServlet; and these are in org.eclipse.jetty.websocket package. I have that jetty-all-9.0.3.v20130506.jar file in my classpath, but the problem is that the org.eclipse.jetty.websocket doesn't contain any classes, as it contains sub-packages. But I can see them in the [API documentation.](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/WebSocketServlet.html)
I don't know the reason why, and I expect you help me make it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong apidocs.

You said you are using Jetty 9.0.3, and then linked to the Jetty 7 javadoc.

Use the Jetty 9 javadoc.

- http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/index.html

There's some information in the jetty 9 documentation about the API as well.

- http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/websockets.html